# Can I make a query relating 2 tables Without primary key and foreign key?

Tags: mysql

I am importing data from excel file to MySQL ,using php MyAdmin as tool manager through PHP. It's a printer report where every user have an unique **user_id** but can make many registers per day what I want is relate one table which contains the user's id and the registers per day and in another table I have information about cost center of each user, what I want to query is the top of users that make more registers per month but not printing the users itself (the info contained on the first  table) but the cost center of that users contained on the second table, etc, if on the first table there is an unique ID per activity it is possible relate to the second table which also contains the users ( **user_id** ) and center cost?

Comment: Please post some sample data and your expected result.

Comment: You don't have to set foreign keys in order to join tables and extract data. Since what you're after is a simple query with a join or two - yes, you can do it without foreign key. If you want to establish referential integrity - then you need a primary and foreign key.